# Aggregate query on a Postgres jsonb array based on a condition

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgres table (`documents`) which has a jsonb column called `details` which holds a jsonb that looks like this:

```
{
  "identifier": "lead_id",
  "callback_url": "http://localhost:3000/supply/internal/api/v3/attempts/9a967788-ad44-499e-93e8-3ce6544f3786",
  "document_ids": [
    "0246ef40-db40-4c07-898c-7c09ad50d3ff",
    null,
    "c155d537-2faf-4397-90ba-741651fdee9d",
    "f926ffc5-6184-44ad-ac16-3da7c0bc3186",
    "68f91648-9297-4f34-b320-d00cec04f52c",
    "2159baf8-55a9-40f9-a998-3b237f370b3a"
  ],
  "identifier_value": "9a967788-ad44-499e-93e8-3ce6544f3786"
}
```

`document_ids` is a jsonb array which holds a list of document ids some of which may be null. I want to run an aggregation query such that in output I get a list of distinct `identifier_value` and the number of document_ids which are null.

For instance, for the above json, the output should be:
`9a967788-ad44-499e-93e8-3ce6544f3786, 1`.

Cant think of how such a query would look like. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`jsonb_array_elements()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

```
select details->'identifier_value', sum((value = 'null'::jsonb)::int)
from documents
cross join jsonb_array_elements(details->'document_ids')
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=41a98ddf1503815d9ce3040714abf85e)

In **Postgres 12** use the `jsonpath` type:

```
select details->'identifier_value', count(d)
from documents
left join jsonb_path_query(details, '$.document_ids[*] ? (@ == null)') as d on true
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6ca92ee84f4b93071004443077862aa5)

Read in the documentation:

- [The SQL/JSON Path Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH)
- [jsonpath Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH)

Comment: Works well! Just one question, how do we order by the sum in the descending order? I tried to alias the sum value and then do an order by - that doesnt work.

Comment: Use the number of the column, see the updated answer.